# My async task does not work correctly, does not call execute

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, execute, runnable

On my button i have the following code:

```
    Log.i(TAG, "!isFirstVideo: " + isFirstVideo);
ConcatenateVideos concatenateVideos = new ConcatenateVideos();
concatenateVideos.setUris(firstVideoUri, fileUri, VideoRecorderActivity.this);
```

This is my asynctask class:

```
public class ConcatenateVideos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private String firstVideoUri, fileUri;
private VideoRecorderActivity videoRecorderActivity;

public void setUris(String firstVideoUri, String fileUri, VideoRecorderActivity videoRecorderActivity) {
    Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "set uris");
    this.firstVideoUri = firstVideoUri;
    this.fileUri = fileUri;
    this.videoRecorderActivity = videoRecorderActivity;
    this.execute();
    Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "set uris2");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "concat do in background");
    FileInputStream videoMain = null, videoToAppend = null;
    try {
        videoMain = new FileInputStream(firstVideoUri);
        videoToAppend = new FileInputStream(fileUri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "concat file not found " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (videoMain != null && videoToAppend != null) {
        concatenateVideos(videoMain, videoToAppend);
        videoRecorderActivity.deleteCancelledRecording(fileUri);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    VideoRecorderActivity.recordButton.setEnabled(true);
    VideoRecorderActivity.okButton.setEnabled(true);
    VideoRecorderActivity.mySurfaceView.setEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(videoRecorderActivity, "Video appended succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "concat touche enabled record, ok ,surface: " + VideoRecorderActivity.recordButton.isEnabled() + "| " + VideoRecorderActivity.okButton.isEnabled() + "|" + VideoRecorderActivity.mySurfaceView.isEnabled());
}
```

In logcat i get:

```
04-11 12:21:42.520: I/VideoRecorderActivity(7927): set uris
04-11 12:21:42.520: I/VideoRecorderActivity(7927): set uris2
```

But i do not get `Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "concat do in background");` that is the first line of the doInBackground class, that is called betweem those 2 lines:

```
Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "set uris");
this.firstVideoUri = firstVideoUri;
this.fileUri = fileUri;
this.videoRecorderActivity = videoRecorderActivity;
this.execute();
Log.i("VideoRecorderActivity", "set uris2");
```

Any ideeas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the full logcat logs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any service run in background for that activity. For Example , when music runs in background with service, the Async task does not parse XML in background as its doInBackground does not work that time and the progress Dialog or progressBar kept spinning.
That is why I used Executor instead of old asynctask.
The problem was that i have a download manager, that works on the background of another activity, and downloads all videos from a database, that do not exist local. And this working with the asynctask class, it could not execute this one.

Answer (score 2):

You will see

```
"set uris2"
```

in the log output before your background task starts executing. There is no guarantee that your `doInBackground()` method will start executing immediately after you invoke `execute()` from the main thread. It is likely to start executing very shortly afterwards, but not immediately.

Maybe you just need to look further down in your logcat buffer to find the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your async task:

```
ConcatenateVideos concatenateVideos = new ConcatenateVideos();
concatenateVideos.setUris(firstVideoUri, fileUri, VideoRecorderActivity.this);
concatenateVideos.execute();   // let's roll
```

Also you should not call `super.onPostExecute();`. There's no point for doing so.

Comment: True, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: true about onpostexecute, but my function was executed, from the setUris function in the ConcatenateVideos Class. And it will after a while start, when the download manager stops for enough time, to let this asynctask start.

Answer (score 0):

Call the

```
new ConcatenateVideos().execute()
```

method on button click and

```
 setUris()
```

method from within the doInBackground() method.

Comment: I also tried this, but it does not work, I have created an answer above, to explain why it did not work, now it does because my class now extends ExecutorAsyncTask and not AsyncTask